# Is "nerdiosity" a real word?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, is-it-a-word

I originally saw this question [here](http://www.nerdtests.com/ft_nt2.php?fmnt), and it made me wonder.

Comment: The correct word would be **nerdosity**, since the root form nerd has no i in it.

Comment: @Oldcat It would just be from _nerdy_, rather than _nerd_ directly.

Comment: I can say with great nerditude that I have never used the term _nerdiosity_ in the past and hope never to do so in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- I've never heard it before
- It looks like a reasonable sounding construction
- it's not in any online dictionary
- it has a google score (as of this moment) of 1060 hits
- ...but most of those hits are about "Is 'nerdiosity' a word?"
- if enough people start using it in a consistent manner then it might be considered a 'real' word.
- I think 'nerdiness' is the appropriate existing term for the expected concept (gscore of 354,000), but that's kinda nerdy to point that out.

Comment: Well it is now!

Comment: Actually I found "Nerdishness"...

Answer (score -2):

Being a nerd, I have to say. It is not a word, word. Like, it is not in the dictionary. But, being as people know it, i'd say it is only as real as BFF. (Best Friends Forever) They are in REAL words, but real in the human mind. There are two different aspects to this decision.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @HawkJade93. This site is different - it's not a discussion (although you can use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome) for that).
It is a site where good answers should become definitive references.